# db_create_table every month

Tags: database, cron

Is it possible to create a table like "tablename_mmyyyy" from my module using hook_cron?
db_create_table does not work. I need to create a new table every month.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! `db_create_table()` works, since it is used from Drupal core and many modules. Probably your code is wrong, but we cannot tell you without seeing it.